# Does Android support jquery?

Tags: jquery, android

I am developing an Android application,here I have decided to put page flip rotation.Just wanted to know whether Android supports jquery so that it would be easier for me to implement the logic

Comment: You must relize that Javascript and Java are two different things.

Comment: You can use [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery), the Android port of jQuery, which allows you to program in native Java in a syntax very similar to jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

If you are developing a [web application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application), then yes, Android will be able to view it properly. Android's browser uses the [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) layout engine, which supports [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript), and therefore [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). But on the other hand, if you are really making a web app, then there is no point in targeting Android specifically: most web-enabled platforms will run it with a few hacks here and there.

I presume you are actually making a native Android app (i.e. one which will be compiled to an .apk file). [This is a completely different thing](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html): it is programmed in a different language ([Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)), and is **not** hosted in a web browser.

Comment: jQuery can be used within a native app but not in the conventional sense. It would have to go through something such as PhoneGap, which would convert everything to work properly as a native app.

Comment: @Blowtar: that's what (I think) I wrote, yes, _"if you are developing a **web application**, Android will be able to view it properly"_, and _"a **native** Android app is programmed in a different language (Java) and **not** hosted in a web browser"_. The question might as well be asking if Android supports Python or Haskell (well, jQuery is not even a language) - you can surely host it in whatever engine you like, as long as the engine runs natively or as a web app.

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking to build a webpage using jQuery & view it in android.. then the answer would be yes (since jquery is a javascript library & android's webkit supports it).. but jquery cannot be used to create apps you need to use java for that.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is Javascript so yes, Android does support jQuery.

(Of course you need something like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), if you want to create a native app)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you could develop the application in jQuery, then you look for [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged android-xml and java, So I assume you are referring to Native Apps. It would be unwise to use JQuery. Because you need to add a browser to your app, make an interface with it, while you could do it with Android API easily and very faster.